# Are near-current man pages or similar doc for bitcoin* available anywhere?

Tags: bitcoin.conf, command-line-options, documentation

I've been unable to find current documentation on command options / bitcoin.conf parameters. I infer that the process of automatic generation of man pages from source is currently in flux ([Manual page generation on 22.x broken](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/22681).) The only commented list of options/parameters I've been able to find([2](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/examples/bitcoin.conf)) is not current to 21.1; e.g., it omits `onlynet`, `externalip`, and `discover` which are accepted by 21.1.

Is a current version available anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially all the parameters are documented in `bitcoind -help`.